# Encoding issue inserting into MongoDB with Python

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode, pymongo

I have a list of dictionaries `data_dump` which contains dictionaries like:

```
d = {"ids": s_id, "subject": subject}
```

I'm following the tutorial trying to do a bulk insert:

```
connection = Connection(host,port)
db = connection['clusters']
posts = db.posts
posts.insert(data_dump)
```

Which fails with the following error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 312, in insert
continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
bson.errors.InvalidStringData: strings in documents must be valid UTF-8
```

Please advise. 
Thanks

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. Some string in data_dump isn't valid utf8. Where did data_dump come from?

Comment: Try using the `codecs.open` function to read the file.  So `open("file.txt", "r")` would become `import codecs; codecs.open("file.txt", "r", "utf-8")`

Comment: @MikeSteder how do i ensure that.. sorry about that. I am simply reading them as a f = open(filename,"r") .. Is there a way to force that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:
 Well.. forced the encoding by 
1) Stripping the string of symbols etc
and then
2) converting ascii to utf-8 by raw.decode('ascii') and then decoded_string.encode('utf8')
Thanks guys.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't afford to lose the non utf-8 characters. So I chose to convert the string to Binary, instead.

As per your example,

```
>>> print subject
u'Math'
>>> d = {"ids": s_id, "subject": bson.Binary(str(subject))} # convert subject from unicode to Binary
```

You can't run full-text searches, which is the latest feature in Mongo, but it works well for everything else.